# ASP.net run javascript in client context

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, restful-url

The scenario:
1) User logs in using a browser tab.
2) user opens a new tab and navigates to my web application.
3) my web application executes following javascript to retrieve the user Email from his logged in session:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    try
    {
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://www.someserver.com/api/getinfo.aspx?EMAIL", false);

        xmlHttp.send(null);

    }

    catch (err) { alert(err.message);}
    var data = xmlHttp.responseText;

    if (data != "") 
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(json.EMAIL);
    }
    else { alert(document.body.textContent);}

</script>
```

4)The problem: if I add this script into the markup of my page.aspx , then run the application with above steps, I fail to retrieve the Email, while if I copy and paste the URL "https://www.someserver.com/api/getinfo.aspx?EMAIL" in a new tab the browser displays the JSON response with Email correctly , what am I missing here?

Comment: _“what am I missing here?”_ - probably first of all, what the browser console has to tell you.

Comment: Well , in Chrome I found out about "chrome same origin policy" and disabled it , I also tried Explorer , yet same issue persists , I get only a null string response

Comment: You should not disable any browser policies or change settings here, likely you won’t be able to do that in the browsers of the people that will eventually use this either … Go read up on CORS, and how to properly enable it from the API side.

Comment: Done and found it is ok to do a GET request Some requests don’t trigger a CORS preflight. Those are called “simple requests” in this article, though the Fetch spec (which defines CORS) doesn’t use that term. A request that doesn’t trigger a CORS preflight—a so-called “simple request”—is one that meets all the following conditions:

The only allowed methods are:
GET
HEAD
POST

Comment: Even for requests that don’t require a pre-flight check, the remote server still must allow for this request to be performed from within a client-side script, by responding with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. That the case here …?

Comment: It being blocked by CORS , yet it mentioned the backend server IP as the origin, so if possible and it runs really from the client browser it should go normally , but how to do that ?...I tried creating HTML file (on my hard drive) with this script and it just works as charm as long as it runs at client side, how to achieve this in the file served by the server?

Comment: The script that you are sending the request to, must issue the appropriate CORS headers to allow for this.